# Delete certain comma delimited data from column

Tags: mysql

I have a column named Genre in my table that contains many various comma delimited content.
The data is saved in different rows in this manner:

```
Adventure, fantasy, sandbox, RPG elements, 
Action, FPS, horror, 
Sports, Soccer,
```

I want to keep just the the first word in every row, and delete the rest. So only keep Adventure, Action, Sports.

Comment: Do not store data as csv. Learn about normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count) function to update the table column

```
update table set Genre = SUBSTRING_INDEX(Genre, ',', 1);
```

Please check:: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index